# Why does this ivar need @protected if @protected is the default?

Tags: objective-c, interface, visibility, instance-variables, protected

```
@interface AClass : SomeType {
@protected
    NSMutableArray* amINotAlreadyProtected; //?
}
```

Why does this code need `@protected` if `@protected` is the default? This code was written by a very experienced programmer, but I would omit the specifier myself.

Comment: `@public`, `@protected`, and `@private` are from an age where properties were hand-coded (they didn't have the `@property` directive), and where iVar access was nearly universal if you needed to get stuff done.  They never got around to deprecating them because parts of Apple frameworks still do use them.

Comment: @JoshCaswell  Because a programmer with about 25 years experience wrote it in his class.  I would have omitted it myself.

Comment: @CodaFi I'd like to disagree with you but then I saw you're rep and thought that I was more likely to be wrong than you. ^^ Therefore I will fraise it as a question - Isn't @private/@protected/@public still used for ivars that the programmer doesn't wan't to use as properties, depending on what subclasses inherit or not?

Comment: @Filip I didn't say it wasn't still used, the thing is that Apple's given us newer better tools to help tighten up encapsulation rules.  `iVar` access is automatically public (well, protected) when written in an interface, but the new feature where an `@implementation` directive can define iVars defeats the purpose of `@private`.  The directives are unneeded in modern ObjC

Comment: @CodaFi Aha, thanks for the clarification! I'm still a novice (at best) ObjC programmer so asked out of curiosity! Well explained!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *no need* for the keyword `@protected` as it is the default behavior.

However, some programmers tend to use it anyways incase a less experienced programmer comes along at a later date and doesn't know this. It can also be mentioned that it increase code readability incase there are some variables that are protected and other private or public.

Comment: There is a need, actually.  Or was.

Answer (score 2):

It is from an age when you might see:

```
@interface Foo:Bar
{
     @private
     … ivars …
     @protected
     … ivars …
}
…
@end
```

That is, while @protected is the default, you would need to use it if you had switched to one of the other variants and wanted to switch back.   And, yes, there were reasons (often bad ones) to ensure that ivar declaration order was preserved from release to release.

Beyond that, including a keyword for the default case ensures that pedantic grey beards (like myself) can be exactly explicit in their declarations.

However, modern additions like `@property` mean that such shenanigans are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I realise that in the case you sighted here we would need the `@protected` since I understand that all variables that follow a keyword `@private` would be private, unless the switch was made back to `@protected`.  That wasn't the case in the question I asked though as there was no `@private` or `@public` preceding it.